# shorten cmd visible file path

Tags: cmd, filepath

I am learning to program java and when I navigate the CMD window to the folder with my programs, the area showing the path becomes very long. I just want to know how to and if it is possible to shorten the path so the input is closer to the left of the window?

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: is it really necessary to travel far to your folder? if not just transfer your folder nearby.

Comment: try `prompt /?` I think, that is, what you need.

Comment: Just wanted to check since this hasn't been active for a while, was my answer helpful for you?

Answer (score 3):

If a) you're working in Windows, and b) most of what you're using regularly is in the same directory or set of subdirectories, then this article I found may be what you're looking for:

https://www.datavail.com/blog/windows-command-prompt-shorten-directory-length-trick/

I had the same annoying problem (having to work 5 or 6 directories deep) and this really cleaned up the CMD display for me.

If that doesn't work for you, my other suggestion would be to follow Keval's advice above and simply move the files farther up in the hierarchy if possible. That's definitely the easiest solution, and Ocham's Razor and all that :)